# HTTP to HTTPS redirect exposes subdirectory instead of redirecting to subdomain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

After several hours of research, I give up!

When I type this: `https://scan.example.com` (note `HTTPS`) it works fine.

But when I type this in browser: `http://scan.example.com`

it goes to: `https://example.com/scan` (it puts the subdomain at the end)

How do I prevent this and make sure it goes to `https://scan.example.com`?

Here is my current `.htaccess` (Which works perfectly for me for everything else besides the issue above):

```
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On

# HTTP to HTTPS canonical redirect
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule (.*) https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# Abort early if the request already maps to (or looks like) a file or directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.\w{2,4}$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# 3. Extensionless URLs for other requests
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule (.*) $1.php [L]
```

*PS: The reason I have `example.com/$1` is because I want to be able to access for example `account.php` in root like this:
`https://example.com/account`.

Comment: "But when I type this in browser: `http://example.com/scan` it goes to: `https://example.com/scan`" - Don't you mean when you type `http://scan.example.com`?

Comment: @MrWhite YES sorry, you are correct.

Comment: Are you hosting multiple domains? Just wondering why you have the first condition... `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example\.com [NC]`?

Comment: @MrWhite no it's just 1 domain. I found this htaccess online to be honest I have no idea what that specific rewritecond is for or what it does :/  By the way I REALLY appreciate your help!!

Comment: That `RewriteCond` directive checks to see if the requested `Host` header _contains_ `example.com` (so it matches `example.com`, `www.example.com` and `anything.example.com`, etc.). But if all requests contain `example.com` anyway, then it's not serving any purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume your `.htaccess` file is located in the root directory of the `example.com` host, in which `/scan` is a subdirectory (that the subdomain presumably points to)? And this `.htaccess` file should apply to both the domain apex and the subdomain?

In which case you'll need to use the `REQUEST_URI` server variable instead of the `$1` backreference in the *substitution* string. Since the `$1` backreference will contain the `/scan` subdirectory when you request the subdomain.

Try the following instead:

```
# HTTP to HTTPS canonical redirect
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+?)\.?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Note sure why you have the first *condition*, unless you are hosting multiple domains?

The above will remove the `www` subdomain, but will preserve any other subdomain, including `scan`. However, this does not specifically canonicalize  www to non-www, since it only redirects HTTP.

Comment: you're awesome. This is the second time you helped me out. Thank you !!!!!

Comment: I'm sorry I just noticed one thing. If I put a php file named "hello.php" in the root subdomain (named: voice) like, I can NOT access it like this:   voice.example.com/hello.   -------- For it to work, I have to actually create a folder named hello in the subdomain and name the php file: index.php. ------ Is there a way I can have a htaccess file that would allow me to to do both? Thanks

Comment: @Maria Where does the `voice` subdomain point to? Does it point to a similarly named subdirectory off the main domains document root? Does this subdomain have its own `.htaccess` file?

Comment: hm, I haven't done any manual pointing. I used the EXACT htaccess content you provided March 8. And no, it does not have it's own htaccess file. Hm, is it better if it does? :/